# Widrow Nguyen MATLAB implementation

Tags: matlab

I tried to implement the Widrow - Nguyen weight initialization on MATLAB 2014a. to compare its performance against HARD RANDOM weight init technique.

```
a = -1;
b = 1;

% WIDROW weights for Layer Input to Hidden Layer 1

sum_sq_wts = 0;

for k=1:30
    iw(:,:) = zeros(num_input, nodes_hidden_layer);
    for i=1:num_input
        for j=1:nodes_hidden_layer
            iw(i,j)=(b-a)*rand(1,1) + a;
            sum_sq_wts = sum_sq_wts + (iw(i,j)*iw(i,j));
         end
    end

    norm = sqrt(sum_sq_wts);
    beta = 0.7*nodes_hidden_layer.^(1/num_input);

    for i=1:num_input
        for j=1:nodes_hidden_layer
            iw(i,j) = beta*iw(i,j)/norm;
        end
    end
    IW{k}=iw';
end

% WIDROW weights for Hidden Layer 1 to output Layer

sum_sq_wts = 0;
for k=1:30
    lw(:,:) = zeros(nodes_hidden_layer,1);
    for i=1:nodes_hidden_layer
        for j=1:1
            iw(i,j)=(b-a)*rand(1,1) + a;
            sum_sq_wts = sum_sq_wts + iw(i,j)*iw(i,j);
        end
    end

    norm = sqrt(sum_sq_wts);
    beta = 0.7*nodes_hidden_layer.^(1/num_input);

    for i=1:nodes_hidden_layer
        for j=1:1
            lw(i,j) = beta*lw(i,j)/norm;
        end
    end

    LW{k}=lw';
end

WidNgu{1,1} = IW;
WidNgu{1,2} = LW;
```

I am generating 30 different set of Widrow weights in the above code. The problem is that the weights generated by the above code generate a lesser performance value for a neural network trained using them as compared to the random set of weights. The problem i used to train was a simple function approx prob.

One thing more interesting i observe is that, the first weight set generated by the above, at times performs better than the random weight approach, but the rest 29 sets that i created are always poor performing.

Where have i gone wrong in this??

Comment: Why is "sum_sq_wts = 0;" not inside loop?

Comment: equals zero for differente layers